# Не проходит проверка столбца php/бд

Tags: php, mysql

> Warning 1: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string
>
> Warning 2: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

```
$row = mysql_query($CONNECT,"SELECT login FROM user WHERE login = login='".$login."'");//Ошибка 1. Если убрать проверку, то в бд залетают данные, и здесь ругается на первый параметр($CONNECT)
if (mysql_num_rows ($row) == "0")//ошибка 2
{
mysqli_query($CONNECT,"INSERT INTO user SET login='".$login."',email='".$email."', password='".$password."'");//это работает
}
```

Comment: `WHERE login = login='".$login."'"`  ничего не смущает?  ......а также порядок входных данных посмотрите в мануале http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php и  у вас

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) - первый параметр SQL-запрос, второй Соединение MySQL. Если идентификатор соединения не был указан, используется последнее соединение, открытое mysql_connect(), у вас наоборот.

Вторая ошибка вытекает из первой, `if (!empty($row) && mysql_num_rows ($row) == "0")`

перебор с параметрами:
`WHERE login = login='".$login."'"` - 
`WHERE login = '".$login."'"`